# How to generate a single list of objects from a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This might be a beginners question, but I am stuck with this.
How to generate a single list of objects from a for loop in python?

Example:
in this for loop

```
for num in range(10):
   print([num])
```

gives the output

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
```

How to get the output in this form

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: You may want to spend more time with the tutorial, especially [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I came up:

```
list(range(10))

[x for x in range(10)]
```

Edit: third way, considering your solution

```
someList = []

for x in range(10):
  someList.append(x)

print(someList)
```

Comment: You could also do `print([x for x in list(range(10))])` here, if you want a one-liner.

Comment: @ladygremlin Using list in your solution is not neccesary, plain range() will do.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right. I got confused the answers/ordering. Yeah, `print(list(range(10)))` and `print([x for x in range(10)])` are one-liners, and then the third answer is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop

```
for num in range(10):
    print([x])
```

You're defining each number in `range(10)` as an individual list, and printing them on new lines. This is why you have 10 resulting lists on new lines.

To combine them into one list, there are multiple answers. Martin Cornejo Saavedra posted a couple solutions above.

```
print(list(range(10))
```

```
print([num for num in range(10)])
```

```
someList = []

for num in range(10):
  someList.append(num)

print(someList)
```

Each of these defines and prints a list with 0-9. Feel free to comment if you have questions!